# Display product name from different store view in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, language

I have multiple store views in my Magento, each one with a different language. All stores have the same products, but each store view has a different product name for that language. Is it possible to set a default store view for the admin?

For example: If someone places an order from the Spanish store view, I would like to go to `Sales > Orders`, open that order and see the products in English instead of Spanish.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product name is stored in DB with order item details in table `sales_flat_order_item` when order generated.

The name will get from the `storeview` from which user orders. So it's not available by default.

You have to do customization for this Like :

In file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml` the order product name is coming from order item.

Instead of that you have to load that product with the help of `product_id` and get and show name from product directly instead of order.

Code

```
<h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></span></h5>
```

Replace with :

```
<?php $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());?>
<h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($p->getName()) ?></span></h5>
```